# invalid property value on border with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i get an "invalid property value" with propriety border (outline too), when i would like to add a border-bottom on a div, and i don't know how fix it.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="maindivs col-md-offset-1 col-sm-7 col-md-7 ">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="navbar">
                    <nav style="border-radius:0px;"class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="container"></div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div style="border-bottom: 1px static black !important;" class="col-lg-12"> 
                    <h2>Coucou</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

that's this line : style="border-bottom: 1px static black !important;"

this problem isn't just that this line, because i have same error if i add this style on this div too:

```
<div class="maindivs col-md-offset-1 col-sm-7 col-md-7 ">
```

Anyone know how I can fix the problem and add a border on my divs ?

Thank's

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got an error because there is no such border style like `static`
Please change it to solid for example.

```
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;" class="col-lg-12"> 
  h2>Coucou</h2>
</div>
```

more reference here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-bottom_style.asp

Comment: oh my god.. sorry it's pathetic, i've been looking for fixing it for one hour.. and it's solid.. Thank u.